# React Router Auto Re-Render

Tags: reactjs

If I have a component that submits a form and makes a post request, and I redirect to a page that shows the user's submissions, how do I make the page re-render?
It will show the most recent version of the page (current submission not included) because dependencies did not change, and I have to refresh manually for the added submission to show. I'm pretty sure I've found the answer for `useHistory` but since I have no idea what am I'm doing(I learned with `useHistory`) I'm using `useNavigate`.

So how would I reflect the most recent submission immediately on redirect?

Answer (score 0):

If the form submission data is coming from an API, then I guess it will automatically fetch new data on redirect. If you want to show form and data on the same page, then after submission of a form, fetch new data from API.

It will be easier to answer if you share your code.

Thank you